# Extension of a continuous function $f: \mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ to a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: analysis, continuity

Prove or disprove that for all continuous functions $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ there is a unique continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $g(x)=f(x),\ \forall x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, this is a task consisting of 2 subtask and this is the latter. In the first one (I think) I have proved that this statement is true for uniformly continuous functions. Now I will try to disprove this statement.

Let us choose $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $d(x,y)<\delta/3$ where $x$ is fixed. Now let us choose $x_n\to x\wedge y_n\to y,\ x_n,y_n\in\mathbb{Q}$. Thereby $d(x_n,y_n)<\delta$. In my other proof, I now used the property for uniformly continuous functions and said that $d(f(x_n),f(y_n))<\varepsilon/2$ and followed that $g$ is uniformly continuous and unique. However, I can't use that premise here, which is why I think that this statement is false as $d(f(x_n),f(y_n))$ can be anything because of $x_n$ not being fixed (and we can't apply the continuity).

How do I go from here / is this the right path in the first place?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is false

Let
$$
f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R\\
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x<\sqrt2$} \\
0, & \text{if $x>\sqrt2$}
\end{cases}
$$
The function is continuos but
$$
\lim_{x\to \sqrt2^{+}}f=0\\
\lim_{x\to \sqrt2^{-}}f=1
$$
So it cant be extended to a continuos function in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Beautiful example!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** A continuous extension will not always exist. But it's true that if a continuous extension exists, it has to be unique. The difference between two continuous extensions is zero on the rationals, so show that the only continuous extension of the zero function $0: \Bbb{Q} \to \Bbb{R}$ to all of $\Bbb{R}$ is the zero function on $\Bbb{R}$, to show that any two continuous extensions of $f: \Bbb{Q} \to \Bbb{R}$ have to agree on all of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: I am struggling to understand the final step. I have proven that the zero function extends uniquely. How do I connect it to f, though? Am I going for an argument along the lines of for any irrational $x$ the value of the function has to be very close to $f(p)$ $p\in\mathbb{Q}$. As the zero function extends uniquely, this has to do the same? Or how exactly do I see the uniqueness?